# Windows 10 upgrade to 16299 - start button doesn't work

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I have recently updated one of my boxes to Redstone 3 16299. After that nothing works out of taskbar, which are Start Menu, Notification Panel, Wifi Panel etc.

Also, the Firefox won't start and in event log there's fatal error in Windows.XUL.UI.dll, but Chrome Browser works.

Any idea how to fix this? I don't know if doing install in-place would help as recent update was exactly this? Should I go with full reinstall.

I have sticker with Windows 8 serial number, will it work on fresh Windows 10 installation from ISO?

Comment: After upgrade from Win7/8, you get a hardware-bound license and don't need a serial number to reinstall. It'll reactivate as soon as you connect the new OS to Internet.

Comment: “I have sticker with Windows 8 serial number” - Windows 8.0+ COA stickers do not have the license key printed on them.  Whatever is printed on the sticker isn’t a Windows 8+ license key.